# Wordpress Image Editor doesn't update thumbs specified with `add_image_size()`

Tags: images

The title somewhat explains the issue. I have a template using bones. I am not sure if this matters or not.

http://themble.com/bones/

In the functions.php file we add some additional thumbnail size options:

```
add_image_size( 'bones-thumb-400', 400, 300, true );
add_image_size( 'bones-thumb-300', 300, 230, true );
add_image_size( 'bones-thumb-200', 600, 200, false );
```

So far so good. All thumbnails are created when we upload an image. When someone uses the image editor in the media library - to crop or rotate the image - the image is saved along with the Wordpress preview thumbnail. Unfortunately the custom thumbnails we have specified are not updated. They remain unchanged.

Has anyone come across this issue before?

How can we get the thumbnails specified in `add_image_size` to update along with the standard Wordpress thumbnails?

Comment: Please regenerate all the images to see the custom sizes of previously uploaded images. You can use the following plugin to get this done http://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/

Comment: I was looking for an automated solution. Perhaps something that can make use of the `wp_save_image_editor_file` filter. What I don't understand is why Wordpress isn't aware of these additional thumbsizes when the editor changes the image as these sizes are specified in the template using a Wordpress function.

Comment: Wordpress is aware of the new image sizes and creates the new thumbs with uploading of all the new image including the new sizes, but the old images which were uploaded prior to the new image size creation doesn't get the new thumbs with new image size

Comment: There are no old images. You misunderstand the question. The additional thumbnails are not updated when using the IMAGE EDITOR. I.e. Crop or Rotate.. the image is updated along with the default wordpress thumbnails. However the custom thumbnails which EXIST are not updated to reflect the changes.

Answer (score 2):

Like it was said, WordPress only generate thumbnails in the new sizes of the new media uploaded. The old images' thumbs doesn't get generated automatically.

For this situation, I strongly recommend the following plugin:

http://wordpress.org/plugins/force-regenerate-thumbnails/

It is pretty simple and unobtrusive. It just adds a new item on the wp-admin menu for you to regenerate every images and its thumbs, every time you insert a new image size on your theme, all in one click.

Comment: Perhaps you misunderstand the question. The template was installed onto a fresh site with no images. An image was uploaded and all the thumbs are created. The image editor was then used on this new image. The custom thumb sizes are not updated when you crop or rotate the image. You appear to be suggesting that thumbnails do not exist for some images because the `add_image_size` function was used after some images were uploaded. This is not the case.

Comment: @user1326244 sorry, I understood now. When you edit an image there are three options: Apply to all images, apply only to thumbnail and apply to all but the thumbnail. It is not working? Have you tested if regenerating the thumbs solved your issue?